# Integrating Google Drive with Google Sites (intranet)

Tags: google-api, google-docs-api, google-drive-api, google-sites

I've setup a Google apps account with the view to use it for my intranet, email, document sharing etc.

With this is Google Sites, in which I have created a basic intranet site, my understanding originally was that Google Sites would enable me to integrate with Google Drive (formerly Google Docs).  I presumed it would be easy to create a "Documents" page in my intranet and then display recent documents that were added to Google Drive.

However if you do create a Documents page in Google Sites then this seems to be completely separate from the Documents in Google Drive.

I have read about Google Picker API but I'm not completely sure this is what I'm looking for.

Has anybody any experience of using Google Drive for business in this way? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Any help would be great thank you

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the use of the term "intranet" here is misleading.

The second sentence of the definition of “Intranet” on Wikipedia states that it “refers to a network **within** an organization”. How can a 'site' in the 'cloud' be an Intranet?

Comment: @DuncanKinnear, I think the term Intranet is quite acceptable. Just because it is hosted in the 'cloud' doesn't mean it can't be private and restricted to people within an organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to get into the scripting a bit. see this link for one way to solve this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites

And yes Sites have a 'file cabinet' which is completely separate form Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

[Overdrive](https://overdrive.io/) provides this functionality. It is a commercial product though. The folder structure within Overdrive matches the Google Drive folder structure. Documents you see listed within a folder in Overdrive are the same as those you can access directly in Google Drive.

I have no affiliation with this company, I've just been trialling it.

Answer (score 0):

Another product you can use to do such kind of i[ntegration is Metadrive](https://metadriveweb.com/getting-started/#Integrate_Metadrive_in_Google_Sites_pages). This tool give you the possibility to create views and search within Google Drive and Team Drives.